# Hovering over an image to layer it over other images

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
img {
  scale: 100%;
position: relative;
z-index: 0px;
}
img:hover{
  scale: 200%;
position: relative;
z-index: 999px !important;
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/16897348514713799124169404858260.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210116-212941_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-113731_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-113809_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-113902_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-113914_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-113940_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114015_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114037_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114217_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114714_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114915_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-114949_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115002_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115104_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115213_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115256_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115728_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-115753_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120006_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120132_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120347_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120649_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120756_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120840_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-120912_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-121121_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-121154_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-121305_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20210117-121418_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_194955_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_195813_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_195838_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_195857_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_195932_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200343_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200013_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200259_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200329_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200410_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200425_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200647_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200733_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200846_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_200931_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_201132_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
   <img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/Screenshot_20230718_202420_eBay.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have several images on a page, some of them are small so I set it to where when the user hovers over them it scales the picture up. The issue is that the image hovered over is covered by some of the other images. I tried "position: relative" and "z-index" but for some reason that prevents the image from scaling up when it's hovered over. I even did "position="relative z-index="0px"" in all of the image tags.

Is there a way to scale up the image and have it be to the front of the other images?

```
img {
  scale: 100%;
}
img:hover{
  scale: 200%;
}
```

This is how I scale up the images.

```
img {
  scale: 100%;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
img:hover{
  scale: 200%;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
<img src="https://itissomething.neocities.org/pics/weirdbay/16897348514713799124169404858260.jpg" width="20%" position="relative"
z-index:="0px"/>
```

This is what I tried, which prevents the scale function from happening.

Edit: The images do scale up now because I missed a semicolon, but they're still not appearing over all of the other images when hovered over, they're still covered up by the images that are underneath them.

Edit 2: added the stacksnippet

Comment: My test doesn't replicate your issue. It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: Why are you putting colon in HTML like this - `z-index:="0px"`? It shouldn't be here. Also, `z-index`'s value should be a plain number (withut `px`).

Comment: @MfyDev Thank you, that was the issue. I was typing super fast and didn't notice the colon, taking out the px helped too. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon ";" in your CSS

```css
img {
  scale: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

img:hover { 
  scale: 200%;    /* <--- added missing semicolon */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

other than that your CSS looks right and your image should change styles and scale up whenever the mouse hovers over any `<img>` element.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize I missed that.
But I still can't get the images to appear over the other images. They scale up but they're still covered by the surrounding pictures.

Answer (score 0):

If you using vs code then use Error Lens extension it will help you and show error in code.